# Plotting the divergence of a vector field along a parametric line

Tags: plotting

I find numerically a scalar field that satisfy Poisson equation. From its gradient I derive a vector field.

```
scalarField = 
 NDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == -Exp[-y - x], 
   u[x, 0] == u[x, 1] == u[-1, y] == u[1, y] == 0}, 
  u, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
vectorField = {-D[scalarField[x, y], x], -D[scalarField[x, y], y]}
```

I want to plot the divergence of the vector field along a line. For example: the one in the figure generate by the following code (x == -0.3; 0 <= y <= 1).

```
Show[StreamPlot[vectorField, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}], 
 Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{-0.3, 0}, {-0.3, 1}}]}]]
```

[image: output]

```
fieldDivergence = Div[vectorField, {x, y}]
```

I can make a 3D plot of it with

```
Plot3D[fieldDivergence, {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1} , Mesh -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "Div"}]
```

But I don't know how to proceed to do a 2D plot. I tried

```
Plot[fieldDivergence[-0.3, y], {y, 0, 1}]
```

Which gives an empty plot. From [looking here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88571/49271) I suspect it has to do with the `fieldDivergence` entity not returning a number.

I don't know what approach to try. How do I plot the divergence of a vector field along a parametric line?

Comment: Is this perhaps what you are looking for? `Plot[fieldDivergence /. x -> -0.3, {y, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot[fieldDivergence /. {x -> -.3, y -> yy}, {yy, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a vector to be shown you need to plot an *area*.  Thus simply restrict your plot to the narrow area enclosing your chosen line:

```
Show[StreamPlot[vectorField, 
    {x, -.31, -.29}, 
    {y, 0, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> 10,  
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}], 
  Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{-0.3, 0}, {-0.3, 1}}]}]]
```

Comment: I am not trying to plot the vector, but its divergence in the points of a given line/curve.